# Prevent Users from Opening Multiple Tabs/Windows in a Web App Using Local Storage

Tags: javascript

To restrict users from opening multiple tabs or windows of our web app simultaneously, we implemented a solution using local storage to track whether the app is already open in another tab or window.

```js
if (localStorage.getItem('appOpenFlag') === 'true') {
    var currentURL = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(currentURL);
    if(currentURL == '/app') {
        window.location.href = "/unauthorized";
    }
} else {
    localStorage.setItem('appOpenFlag', 'true');  
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('appOpenFlag', 'false');
    });
}
```

This solution generally works fine, BUT if the user's browser is forcefully closed or crashes, the appOpenFlag remains set to true, even though no app window is open.

how to improve this implementation to handle scenarios where the browser is unexpectedly closed or crashes? or should we look for another solution?

Comment: You cannot really prevent users from having multiple open tabs to your site, so maybe your energy would be better spent making sure your application can handle that.